# Why do I get a "Value of type 'TableViewController' has no member 'place' ''?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am tying to download some data from parse (a string) and I get the error

`"Value of type 'TableViewController' has no member 'place'` on the line that says :

`self.place.append(spotdetail.name!)`

I have this as a global var :

```
var place = [""]
```

and this is my code in the ViewDidLoad:

```
let query = PFObject.query()
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) in

    if let skateparks = objects {
        for object in skateparks {        
            if let spotdetail = object as PFObject! {                            
                self.place.append(spotdetail.name!)        
                self.tableView.reloadData()                           
            }        
        }        
    }

    print(place)               
})
```

What can I change to make it work as I don't understand why it doesn't recognize the `var place` as it is in the same view controller (tableView)

thanks!

Comment: I doubt the error message occurs on that line since it does not have anything to to with the line. Please show more context or post a screenshot of the error as proof.

Comment: sorry there was an error typing the question, it is corrected now @luk2302

Comment: If it's a global var, then you just say `place.append` – it's not an instance member of self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everywhere in closure you should use `self` keyword for properties:

```
print(self.place)
```

Comment: In the line where the problem occurs I do have a self `self.rideSpots.append(spotdetail.name!)` If I add a self in print I get an error

Comment: @stephenD Its all about where do you declared `place` variable. If it is your view controller class property, then you should use self keyword. But seems like you declared it at start of `viewDidLoad` method, then you should not use self keyword for it, because closure will capture it for you.

Comment: Thanks ! moved the var and it is now working,

Answer (score 0):

As originaluser2 pointed out you are using a global variable so you do not need to user self.place.  Also i'm not sure what you are subclassing in PFObject, but your func name is findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock and you are reloading your table data there.  Always keep in mind that you can only  interact with the UI on the main thread. This will cause errors, so you can either pass back a callback, or do a GCD call to the main queue and then reload the data there.